# How to correctly use poco::Thread and poco::Timer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, synchronization, poco

I would like to have several threads which change the value of certain elements periodically. Let's say I have some kind of run-method changing the value and a certain amount in milliseconds of sleep afterwards. I do need to be able to change the interval a) right after the change and b) after the sleep. I also need a possibility to change between single execution and repeated execution in timed intervals.

The problem with using a Timer is, that I do not have the possibilities I have with using threads directly, like naming or using conditions.

Can anybody please give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve rather than how you are trying to achieve it?

Comment: Just edited my original question.